# Swipe to delete entire section in UITableView (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've had a lot of success in the past using [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) to swipe to dismiss cells, but my current task calls to swipe an entire section in the same behavior.

I currently have a swipe gesture recognizer in the UITableView, when the swipe gesture is triggered, I calculate the section the touch was recieved, and delete the objects that populate that section (in core data), then call the delete animation:

```
//Delete objects that populate table datasource 
for notification in notifications {
    notificationObject.deleted = true
}

DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.save()

let array = indexPathsToDelete
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
array.forEach(indexSet.add)

//Delete section with animation            
self.notificationsTableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: .left)
```

This works, but is not ideal. Ideally we would like the whole section to drag with your finger (and when released at a certain point, it goes off screen), similar to MGSwipeTableCell.  What is the best way to approach this?  Is there another library which allows swipe to delete sections (I can't find any)?  Or is this something I will have to create myself.

Comment: Swipe gestures on top of `UITableView`s are usually dirty because not only do `UITableView`s react to swipe gestures themselves but their cells do as well. Here is a thought, instead of intending to swipe over a cell in the section to initiate the swipe, why not create a custom header cell for the section. So then it would be that header view that will contain its own swipe gesture (or button) to reveal a "Delete" button. And when that button is pressed in the header use the `.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: .left)` method to delete the entire section.

Comment: that is a good idea but the issue is not the swipe gesture; the issue is that the whole section and its nested table needs to be dragged along with the touch of the finger if you get what I am saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but the idea is below. Take a view (`self.header`) and use the `touchesBegan...` method to detect the user placing their finger on screen. Then, follow the finger with the `touchesMoved...` method and calculate the difference between the last offset and the next. It should grow by 1 (or more) depending on how fast the user is moving their finger. Use this value to subtract the `origin.x` of the cell's `contentView`.

```
var header: UIView!
var tableView:UITableView!
var offset:CGFloat = 0

override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Touches Began. Disable user activity on UITableView
    if let touch = touches.first {
        // Get the point where the touch started
        let point = touch.location(in: self.header)
        offset = point.x
    }
}

override public func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {

        // Get the point where the touch is moving in header
        let point = touch.location(in: self.header)

        // Calculate the movement of finger
        let x:CGFloat = offset - point.x
        if x > 0 {
            // Move cells by offset
            moveCellsBy(x: x)
        }

        // Set new offset
        offset = point.x
    }
}

override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Reset offset when user lifts finter
    offset = 0
}

func moveCellsBy(x: CGFloat) {
    // Move each visible cell with the offset
    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
        // Place in animation block for smoothness
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            cell.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: cell.contentView.frame.origin.x - x, y: cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width, height: cell.contentView.frame.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks brandon, I was actually going to do this very logic before reading your answer.  Was just hoping that there was a library already out there that does that.

Comment: No worries ;). Maybe you can make a small library that does do that?

Comment: Its definitely in the agenda, shouldnt be very difficult at all :D

Answer (score 0):

Brandon's answer is correct, however, INSPullToRefresh library has issues when using touches began and other touch delegate methods.

What I had to do was implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer and track the touch  when that gesture recognizer event is fired