# Swipe to delete on entire section in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, sections

I have a `UITableView` which has a **variable amount of sections** and every section has a **variable amount of rows**. Every section contains a section header, a section footer and the rows for that section. They are shown and displayed inside a container. Everything up until now works as expected. To demonstrate what my `UITableView` currently looks like:

[image: current tableview]

I am now trying to implement the possibility to swipe left on the **entire section**, so that the header of the section, the rows inside this section and the footer of this section move to the left and display another `UIView`. I am capable of swiping the cells separately, but enabling this feature on the entire sections have caused headaches for the past two days. This is what I would like to achieve:

[image: desired result]

I have thought about implementing `UIGestureRecognizers` but I am afraid they might conflict with my `UITableView`. Also, I started implementing it, but I would not know how to move solely the section on which was swiped to the left.

Then I thought I could maybe implement a `UIScrollView` as container for each section. How I would accomplish this is still a mystery to me, but it seems like a possible solution if this could be done.

Furthermore I am out of ideas and stuck on how this should be done. It's something I have not found on the Internet so far - at least no working examples of some kind so I have zero inspiration on how to achieve the effect.

I therefor would like to ask if somebody has an idea of how this could work and what I have to keep in mind when implementing this. Every clue pointing me towards a working solution is gratefully appreciated!

EDIT: I have already seen the possible duplicate this afternoon. However, the suggestion there shows touchesBegan() on the header, which does not work in my case as I need the entire section to be "draggable".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe to delete entire section in UITableView (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739072/swipe-to-delete-entire-section-in-uitableview-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way you can implement this is with a vertical stackview containing  views that contains a tableview and the trash icon. When a user swipes left on the tableview header, it will show the hidden trash icon in the view. I would think that each tableview only has one section so it will be easier to keep track of which "section" the user has swiped.

Comment: I have indeed thought about implementing a UICollectionView where each item contains a UITableView. However, this resulted in some unexpected behavior with the UITableViews being wrongly associated. There are a lot of interactions inside the cells, so I wanted to remain everything in one UITableView if that would be possible.

Comment: If that were the case.. The only option I could think of is getting the frame of the section and presenting a view with the same tableview with the icon on top. However, I'm not sure how smooth that would look.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently managed to arrange a similar solution. I take the rectangle of the section with rect(forSection:int), add a UIPanGestureRecognizer in which I add a UIView on top of the UITableView if touches began, I calculate the location of the finger and let the cudtom UIView follow. When a certain point (100 from left edge of the UITableView) is reached, the section gets removed with deleteSections(indexSet:with:).

This works. It does the job, but it adds an overlay to the section rather than pushing it to the left.

Therefor I am asking of someone knows if there is any way of setting the offset for one specific section or for an area of a UIView, so I can offset the rectangle of the section. I have been able to setContentOffset on the entire UITableView but this is not the desired result.

If there is no way to do this, I would consider keeping the solution I have now or maybe implement a snapshot feature which takes a screenshot and crops the rect of the frame, adding this UIImage to the custom view to simulate the section. But that would be tricky. Any ideas for this idea are also welcome.